# SMS using SMPP or/and SS7

Tags: smpp, ss7

I have a crucial question related to sending SMS trough SMPP or SS7.

Case:
We are connected to all local operators using SMPP(we already have an agreement with each one). The fact is that we are able to send SMS to all local operators and actually receive the DLR(deliver_sm), but there a lot of cases when we are not receiving anything back.

By the other hand, we have an E1 connection running SS7 with one local operator for voice purposes. I was thinking if it is possible to SEND SMS using this SS7 E1 connection? There is couple of hardware in the market that provide this functionality.

My principal concerns are:
- What should I check before buying this SS7 SMS hardware, to be sure that this will work in our SS7 E1 connection?
- Can the operator blocks the SMS that are comming from the E1 SS7 connection?
- If we actually send a SMS usign the SS7 E1 connection, where will be receive the DLR, in the SMPP connection, or in the E1 SS7?
- Will be able to have dynamic sender id if we send SMS trough the SS7 E1?

Thanks and best regards,

Claudio

Answer (score 5):

In order to send SMS over SS7, you should have a SMS-Center-like software that will submit SMS over SS7 MAP protocol (using MT-Forward-SM command preceded by a SRI-for-SM Send Routing Information for Short Message to get subscriber location). Your E1 connection is probably only enabled for voice (ISUP) and will probably not support the sending of MAP commands, or those MAP commands will be discarded by your operator.

Additionally to having a full SS7 connectivity usually provided by a partner mobile operator, you will need other requirements:

- Your platform should have been allocated a PC (Point Code) and GT (Global Title) from the operator providing you SS7 connectivity.
- the operator should allow you to submit those MAP messages and route them to their recipient operators, you could only reach mobile operators having a roaming agreement with your hosting operator.
- SMS delivery is done in at least two steps: first you retrieve the subscriber location by querying the HLR (Home Location Register) of the recipient mobile network using a SRI-for-SM command, then you submit the SMS to be mobile subscriber serving MSC/VLR using a MT-Forward-SM command. You could only reach HLR of operators having a roaming agreement with your host mobile operator. Those HLRs will usually check your Global Title to verify you are authorized to submit SMS.
- In order to support all call flows and prerequisites, you need not only the SS7 hardware but also a SMS-Center software. You could source it from a commercial supplier or build it, but in the latest case plan to allocate appropriate resources as it is fairly complex.

The above is only a brief summary of the call flows and associated requirements, in the real life, this could be much more complicated. For a detailed description of SMS protocol over SS7, please refer to the ETSI/3GPP main specification for SMS that you could find here: http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/123000_123099/123040/12.02.00_60/ts_123040v120200p.pdf (Technical Realization of the Short Message Service).

You understand it is very difficult to be able to submit SMS directly over the SS7 network without having not only appropriate SS7 HW and SMSC software but also a strong partnership with a very friendly mobile network operator that will grant you access to its SS7 network and authorize you to send SMS on his behalf.

An easier alternative is to contract with one of the SMS brokers operating exactly this kind of infrastructure, you will submit to them over SMPP but they will deliver over SS7. This will enable you in most cases to get delivery status acknowledgement and use dynamic sender id.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding case you mentioned -the lots of cases that you are not receiving back anything- If you have a look details of SMPP specification you may find the answers of many of them. Apart from standard SMPP messages(**submitSM** and **deliverSM**) there are some others that helps you either track or change the short message you submitted from your external short message entity application:

- Checking submitSM response codes such as invalid source, destination address or SMSC vendor specific error codes
- Using **querySM** message to query the status of short message with message id which is returned by SMSC/SMSGW as response to submitSM. With help of it you can query delivery status of your short message and decide what to do.
- **CancelSM** enables application to delete pending SMS for delivery on SMSC/SMSGW queue. Use case can be : SMS is submitted with delivery report flag but delivery report for final status has not received yet, you can delete this short message using cancelSM
- By means of **empty SMS** you can verify that recipient terminal is on or off or out of coverage. You send empty SMS using your ESME application with final status delivery report flag and wait the delivery report. If delivery report does not reach your end let's after 15 minutes you may assume that terminal is either off or out of coverage.
- Using **relative time format** as SMS validity period to set how long it can be queued for delivery on SMSC/SMSGW. But be aware that SMSC operator can impose a limit on relative time offsets and may reject a message that exceeds such a limit (e.g. 24 hours)